# writing data to filesystem from hive queries in hdinsight

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I see that its viable to write query results to filesystem in hadoop: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries

How do I save a query result in case of hdinsight in a folder which is accessible from blobstorage.

I tried something as below but was not successful.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/example/distinctconsumers' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' select consumerid from distinctconsumers;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Language manual clearly states below

```
 LOCAL keyword is used, Hive will write data to the directory on the local file system.
```

If you remove 'LOCAL' from your query them it will work.

NOTE: the result might not be a single file but a list of files (one from each task)